# Setting up OrientDB image on Microsoft Azure platform

Tags: azure, orientdb

I am trying to setup OrientDb instance under Azure. I followed the procedure [documented](http://orientdb.com/orientdb-microsoft-azure/) at [OrientDB website](http://orientdb.com/orientdb-microsoft-azure/) (`OrientDB Community Edition 2.0.10`). I was able to setup the instance as described. After setting up all I could do is to ssh to the instance using the `username:db` as mentioned in the document (well I could have used any name, but for simplicity I followed word to word from the doc). I couldn't find information on `user:root` or `user:orientdb` (and a few other users and groups) that were part of this image. Additional users/groups are available in `/etc/passwd`. I am unable to get access to those users/groups. I am unable to find the documentation.

I tried to connect to the OrientDb web interface http://10.0.0.4:2480 (hosted on internal network interface within Azure region) and it doesn't even allow me to create db or login. It keeps asking for the username and password which I dont know (not documented).

Anyone know where can I found additional documentation/help on this image.

I can always setup a plain linux OS, install java and setup orient-db and configure it to use azure storage (bound as local disk storage). As much as possible, I would like to use the image provided by the orient-db team as I think it would come with recommended configuration.

I want to host/run a clustered orientdb instance on Azure. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @colin @pabzt Both provided detailed next level useful information on setting up OrientDB on Azure. As per @colin I was able to reset root password using `sudo passwd root` and was able to take complete control of the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem today. You could connect using ssh. The default password and username can be found in the "orientdb-server-config.xml":

```
/opt/orientdb/config/orientdb-server-config.xml
```

The only thing i can't do is accessing the OrientDB Studio. While i can connect to the public ip address of the vm using ssh, i cant open the OrientDB Studio on port 2480 using the same public ip address. I tried adding an inbound securty rule in the network security settings for the orientdb vm but that didn't help. Still can't connect.

**EDIT 22.10.2015 21:00**

But I'm sure the password and username is working (from "orientdb-server-config.xml"), because i tried using the binary protocol on port 2424 with the "official .Net Driver" for OrientDB in a client application written in C#, and they worked. I was able to connect and create a new Database. Also i was able to access the default database: "GratefulDeadConcerts". I used the same public ip address that i used to connect via ssh.

I compared the OrientDB VM created by the image from the azure marketplace and couldn't find the option to set Endpoints (Azure VM Settings). All my other Azure VMs have this option in the Azure VM Settings. I always used the Endpoint settings to open ports on the virtual machines i have. It seems that i can only use the Endpoints for ssh and port 2424. Maybe those are the ones which are open by default. Any Ideas?

**EDIT 23.10.2015 14:00 Uhr**
Okay i found the solution, the OrientDB image from the azure marketplace works. I just added a new securty rule that allows connections from any port (*) to port 2480 (OrientDB Studio) and now it works.

Comment: for me it says the following     <users>
        <user resources="*" password="0EC98ED732DB7DD3BB4B74BD0CAEC154B910050E25BC29BE3E5AAEE7EC3E71BD" name="root"/>
        <user resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" password="guest" name="guest"/>
    </users>
I do not know the root password

Comment: Yes, you could change the password if you want and use it in combination with the username (in this case it says "root") to get access to the database using the API or you can also use it with OrientDB Studio (Port: 2480) to manage the database.

Comment: Ok. I will try now. Do you know how I can find the root passwd (system root password) The above passwd didn't work

Comment: See: `http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Tutorial-Run-the-server.html` for further information. Also you might need a Framework/Library to access the database using the binary protocol (`Port: 2424`), which is also discribed on the page. In Addition you could also use the REST protocol on `Port: 2424`.

Comment: @colin sorry I can't comment (not enough points) on your post. I updated my answer. Im also sure that the db was running.

Comment: Thanks for the second edit. I added inbound rule for 2480 and I was able to access studio.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to ssh to the virtual machine using the username and password that you specified when you created the Azure instance.

To obtain the credentials for Studio, Pabzt is right, just take a look at the  sections of orientdb-server-config.xml and look for the root user.  Its password will be auto-generated.  You can change this.

Pabzt, regarding accessing Studio, you might make sure the OrientDB instance is still runnning:

sudo systemctl status orientdb

Usually, ports 22 and 2480 are open by default in the OrientDB Azure image.  So, it's strange you can't access it.

Comment: I am able to ssh. The orientdb says its running (active). The users section has the following <users> <user resources="*" password="0EC98ED732DB7DD3BB4B74BD0CAEC154B910050E25BC29BE3E5AAEE7EC3E71BD" name="root"/> <user resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" password="guest" name="guest"/> </users> Does it mean root passwrd is 0EC98ED732DB7DD3BB4B74BD0CAEC154B910050E25BC29BE3E5AAEE7EC3E71BD or is it encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and realized I had missed something. On Azure go to All Resources, click on the Network Security Group for your server, and add an Inbound Security Rule allowing TCP port 2480. I didn't have to add anything using iptables on the server even though 2480 is not listed there. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoints, by default are set to 22 and 2480.  Strange that you had to set 2480 to * for incoming.  But I'm glad you got it to work!

Comment: I didn't get inbound rule for 2480 by default. I had default inbounds created for 22 and 2424 but not 2480. With @Pabzt response, I added inbound rule and was able to access orientdb studio after that

Answer (score 0):

The root in the orientdb-server-config.xml is just for OrientDB and is not related to the system root account.

You should be able to sudo as the system username that you specified when you created the Azure VM.  If you can sudo commands you should be able to change the system root password as well.

Comment: This worked. I logged in as azure user I created and executed 'sudo su'. This logged me in as root and then I was able to change the password. Thanks